# Weblogic AdminServer achieves state 'RUNNING' only when network connection is disabled (localhost)

Tags: jdbc, weblogic

Running WebLogic 10.3.6 on localhost with nothing deployed yet, the state of the AdminServer is always 'SHUTDOWN' and I get this console message:

```
<08-Aug-2013 12:24:06 o'clock IST> <Warning> <Log Management> <BEA-170011> <The LogBroadcaster on this server failed to broadcast log messages to the admin server. The Admin server may not be running. Message broadcasts to the admin server will be disabled.> 
<08-Aug-2013 12:24:07 o'clock IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING> 
<08-Aug-2013 12:24:07 o'clock IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode>
```

When I disconnect from the network, the AdminServer state is 'RUNNING', but I get an exception because my remote jdbc connection can't be achieved.

```
<08-Aug-2013 12:28:28 o'clock IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application 'JDBC Data Source-0' due to error          weblogic.application.ModuleException: .
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:327)

Caused By: weblogic.common.ResourceException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection. The DBMS driver exception was: IO Error: Unknown host specified 
at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.createResource(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:283)
```

Followed by the same notice that the server is 'Running'

```
<08-Aug-2013 12:28:41 o'clock IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode>
```

Why is it that I get issues for jdbc or the AdminServer but cannot have both working simultaneously? Also, what does the message that the 'Server state has changed to RUNNING' when in the WL Console it says that AdminServer is not running?

Comment: Does the JDBC connection ever work? I have seen cases where a server will report RUNNING but it's actually in a bad state because the jdbc connection failed.

Comment: When look at the JNDI Tree Structure, I get: "The server you requested is not available" so possibly not. Does this tell you anything?

Comment: Under "Summary of Servers" -> Configuration, AdminServer has a State = SHUTDOWN but  HEALTH = OK
Settings for JDBC Data Source -> Monitoring -> Statistics, State = Running. So I don't know which to believe :)

Comment: That's very strange. If you go to that same Monitoring tab for the JDBC Data Source can you try to test the connection to see what happens? You'll want to tail the admin server log when you do it.

Comment: It was successful: "Test of JDBC Data Source-0 on server AdminServer was successful". The AdminServer output was simply: "<Warning> <netuix> <BEA-423420> <Redirect is executed in begin or refresh action. Redirect url is /console/console.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=JdbcDatasourcesJDBCDataSourceMonitorTestingPage.>"